# How would you set up Node to handle SSEs with Redis pub/sub?

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, publish-subscribe, server-sent-events

EDIT: All good! This is a working example. Just needed a conditional, per the comment below. I updated the code snippet to reflect the change. So much functionality with so little code! I'm realizing the tab spinning is because the connection is still open - because I told it to stay open. In a more realistic application, that connection will be held open from an xhr GET call behind the scenes, with messages to publish via xhr POST calls.

---

So, I *kinda* have this working, but I'm missing something, since the tab icon says the page is continually loading, and my messages are bleeding across channels. Here is what I have:

```js
import express from 'express';
import redis from 'redis';

const app = express();
const port = 1244;

const redisOptions = {
  url: 'redis://redis:6379/1'
}
const subscriber = redis.createClient(redisOptions);
const publisher = redis.createClient(redisOptions);

app.get('/', (_req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.get('/rooms/:roomId', (req, res) => {
  // setup headers for the response in order to get the persistent HTTP connection
  res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'text/event-stream',
    'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive'
  });
  subscriber.on("message", function (channel, message) {
    // res.write('id: UniqueID\n');
    // res.write('event: add\n');
    // res.write('retry: 10000\n');
    if (req.params.roomId === channel) {
      let data = "Message: " + message + " on channel: " + channel
      res.write('data: ' + data + '\n\n'); // whenever you send two new line characters the message is sent automatically
    }
  });
  subscriber.subscribe(req.params.roomId);
});

app.get('/rooms/:roomId/messages/:foo', (req, res) => {
  publisher.publish(req.params.roomId, `{\"message\":\"Hello from ${req.params.foo}!\"}`);
  return res.status(200).send('ok');
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

And here is what it looks like in the browser:

[image: app responses]

As you can see the pub/sub side of things seem to be working, and the Sever Sent Events seem to be making their way to the browser! But... there is a scoping issue of some sort? I don't seem to understand how Node and its event based IO works. I'm fairly new to Node. Anyone have any thoughts on how to "fix" this? It feels close, but I've hit a wall.

Comment: *bleeding across channels* - wrap the code INSIDE the on message handler with `if (req.params.roomId === channel) { .... }`